# Center website background on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-position

I've seen this trick on many websites and I want to make it for a project of my own.
I have an image `background.jpg` that is VERY BIG, just to be ready for any screen size.
I wish to center the background image to the visitor's window.
I mean, while scrolling the window content will move but the background will stay in place - centered vertically and horizontally.

BTW most of the viewers will have old crappy PC's so it'd better not flicker, if it'll be JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
body
{
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* you know... don't repeat... */
    background-position: center center; /*center the background */
    background-attachment: fixed; /*don't scroll with content */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try what is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3RRYe/3/ 
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3RRYe/3/show/)
see if that works for ya ^_^

Comment: That should just be center, not center top - he wants vertical centering too.

Comment: `body
{
 background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}` ain't workin'

Comment: I wish to center on the SCREEN not page!

Answer (score 0):

put your image on the body background:

```
body{ background-image:url('your/image/url'); }
```

and put a div within the body:

```
<body><div class="div-body">{your site's contents}</div></body>
```

and create a css selector like this:

```
.div-body{
   overflow:scroll;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}
```